# GlassFish 4 glassfish-acc.xml file: What is the purpose of the name attribute of the target-server element?

Tags: glassfish, glassfish-4, iiop

In the GlassFish 4 glassfish-acc.xml file, what is the purpose of the name attribute of the target-server element?

It seems that this file has something to do with IIOP.

Different installs of GlassFish 4 have different values for that attribute, but the rest of the files are exactly the same.  Some example values of this attribute are:

sc11152542.us.oracle.com

sc11152550.us.oracle.com

I am trying to standardize the configs of some inherited GlassFish 4 servers.  They are not clustered.  Would it be OK for me to use the same value for all my servers?  If so, does it matter which value I choose?

I read the documentation from the following link, but it was too tautological to be useful.

https://glassfish.java.net/docs/4.0/application-deployment-guide.pdf

The documentation also appears to be out of date, since it refers to sun-acc.xml instead of glassfish-acc.xml, and because it uses version 1.2 of the DTD while the glassfish-acc.xml files that I've seen use version 1.3.

Comment: is `sun-acc.xml` related to `glassfish-acc.xml`?  Are they different versions of the same information?  One is for newer Glassfish servers?  I suppose so:  https://www.java.net/forum/topic/glassfish/glassfish/change-appclient-behavior-sun-accxml-now-glassfish-accxml

Comment: I assume the answer is yes to all 3 of your questions.   I no longer maintain the servers in question, however, so my question is moot now (for my current work, but not for general knowledge or for other devs).  I can't remember what I did, but I assume that I just chose one value and standardized on that.  I didn't notice any repercussions from whatever I did.

Comment: yes, 3 yeses.  as far as I know, at least.  thanks.